# How to work around hibernation when automating the running of a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to run a macro at specific time each day which works fine while I am at work but over weekends my computer goes into sleep mode and the code does not run. How do I work around this?

```
Sub Scheduler()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "TheScheduledSub"
End Sub

Sub TheScheduledSub()
    MsgBox "TheScheduledSub() has run at " & Time
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure Windows task scheduler to wake your computer as specified times (with specified frequency)

From [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/) link:

- Open the Task Scheduler by typing Task Scheduler into the Start menu if you are running Windows 10 or 7 (or Start Screen if you are using Windows 8.x) and pressing Enter
- In the Task Scheduler window, click the Create Task link to create a new task.
- Name the task something like “Wake From Sleep.” You may also want to tell it to run whether a user is logged on or not and set it to run with highest privileges.
- On the Triggers tab, create a new trigger that runs the task at your desired time. This can be a repeating schedule or a single time.
- On the conditions tab, enable the Wake the computer to run this task option.
- On the actions tab, you must specify at least one action for the task – for example, you could have the task launch a file-downloading program. If you want to wake the system without running a program, you can tell the task to run cmd.exe with the /c “exit” arguments
- Save your new task after configuring it.

You can also configure a task to send your computer [back to sleep](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30758/make-your-pc-shut-down-at-night-but-only-when-youre-not-using-it/).

You could additionally use the Scheduler to kick off your script.

Adding cmd text

[image: CMD action]

Comment: I just want to wake the computer up. I understand what you have posted up to this line "you can tell the task to run cmd.exe with the /c “exit” arguments" I am not sure what I type in program script field do I type " cmd.exe /c exit " ?

Comment: See edit for where to put text

Comment: really appreciate the help but.... I have just discovered that I do not have rights to use the Task Scheduler! It does not accept my user name and password. :(

Comment: you can request IT to set it up for you. It is a few minutes effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off hibernation with a shell command:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

and you can use the [`Shell` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function) to run shell commands.

For more info read: [How to disable and re-enable hibernation on a computer that is running Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920730/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-on-a-computer-that-is-running).

Of course don't forget to turn it on again when you close that file.